# If element found change page content

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change page content if element exist on page ?

if (window.frames[0].document.getElementById('xl')) { //load content of page acta.html}

Answer (score 1):

Only if the content loaded in the frames is in the same domain of the page where the script is executed. See the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) – SOP.

Otherwise you can't access to the frame's DOM.

If the page are in the same domain, then your code is perfectly valid – assume the page in the frames is loaded.

**Update**:

To change the content, then you can simple change `location` object of the frame:

```
if (window.frames[0].document.getElementById('xl')) {
    window.frames[0].location.href = "acta.html";
}
```

If you have a reference to the frame / iframe element instead of the window's (`frame[0]`), you can also use the `src` attribute.

You can also change the top window's location just doing:

```
window.location.href = "acta.html";
```

However that will change, of course, the URL of the page too. If you want to keep the URL as before, you should use another iframe that basically wraps your current main window and the hidden frame. So the URL displayed in the address bar will not change even if you change the content of the first frames to "acta.html".

Another approach could be use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) object to makes a http call and load your page's source, then replace the body of the current page with the one's retrieved by the XHR. However, that's ugly. This kind of redirection, keeping the same URL, should be done on server side, not on client side.

Comment: the page and iframe are on the same domain. but what I need to enter between {  } ?

Comment: So you have page A that contains an iframe with page B. So you want to change the location of page A if page B contains a certain element?

Comment: I have page B within page A(index.html). Iframe page B is hiden. When page B contain element 'xl' I need to load different content on page A(acta.html content), but still be the same (index.html) and change only content and not the url.

Comment: You can't. I will update the answer to be more precise, but that is the short answer in general.